# Popen.stderr.readline hangs if the stderr string is not terminated with '\n'

Tags: python, popen, readline, stderr, raw-input

I have the below script b.py

```
import sys
sym = "NEW WORD"
print >> sys.stderr, "You must enter a single word.\n"
sys.stderr.write(("Please enter the correct word for %s\n"
                  "Or enter 'n' if it is not correct: ") % sym)
sym = raw_input()         
sys.stderr.write(("Please enter the correct word for %s\n"
                  "Or enter 'n' if it is not correct: ") % sym)
```

I am trying to run this script using Popen where I am facing the issue. That is, after reading few lines, it gets stuck. The same works (no hanging) if I have a '\n' appended to the statement after `correct:` otherwise not.

```
cmd2 = ['python', 'b.py']
In [43]: p =  Popen(cmd2 , stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
In [44]: p.stderr.readline()
Out[44]: 'You must enter a single word.\n'
In [45]: p.stderr.readline()
Out[45]: '\n'
In [46]: p.stderr.readline()
Out[46]: 'Please enter the correct word for NEW WORD\n'
In [47]: p.stderr.readline()
<Hangs>
```

Why is this happening so ? Also is there any solution for this (apart from making any changes to b.py)

But things work fine when I run the script b.py manually

```
python b.py
You must enter a single word.

Please enter the correct word for NEW WORD
Or enter 'n' if it is not correct: HELLO
Please enter the correct word for HELLO
Or enter 'n' if it is not correct:
```

Comment: That may be because writing to a stream doesn't necessarily happen at `write` time, but at `flush` time, and the *EOLN* automatically triggers such a `flush`.

Comment: But when I run the script manually, things are working fine. Please see the edit for the script output. Could you tell why is the issue not happening at that time?

Comment: There's a `raw_input()` in *b.py*. How do you provide input when calling it via `Popen`? When running directly, I assume you enter some value.

Comment: I am using `p.stdin.write("HELLO")` to provide the input. But since the above statement gets hung, I am unable to provide the input

Comment: I think that you created some kind of a deadlock here (`sys.stderr`'s buffered output combined with `raw_input()`). Bottom line is: if you want the text to be written to stream by `write`, use a `\n` at the end, or call `sys.stderr.flush()` or disable buffered IO.

Comment: Is there any other way apart from modifying the script (b.py) ?

Comment: Check [\[Python\]: Miscellaneous options](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#generic-options) (`-u`).